# CollectionViewCell loading with nil value after reloadData func

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I made a function to fetch data for an empty array that I'm using for a collectionView. I'm pulling the information from two different child nodes. The first being the "users" tree and the second being the "profile_images", using the UID from users to find the corresponding images. The cell populates when the view loads. My issue is that when the cell populates, I'm getting a nil value for one of the values.

I tried to add the array to the collectionViewCell instead of the view controller. I've also been reading the developer notes on prefetching data but it makes it seems like it's used for cells that have yet to be loaded.

```swift
var matches = [MatchData]()
// function to retrieve firebase data
private func populateInbox() {
        if let uid = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid {
            // Supply Matches for users first
            let match = MatchData()
            Database.database().reference().child("users").observe(.childAdded) { (snapshot) in
                let matichUID = snapshot.key
                if matichUID != uid {
                    Database.database().reference().child("profile_images").child(matichUID).observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (data) in
                        if let imageDict = data.value as? [String: AnyObject] {
                            match.matchImage = imageDict["imageOne"] as? String
                            print(match.matchImage)
                        }
                    })
                    if let dictionary = snapshot.value as? [String: AnyObject] {
                        print(uid, dictionary)
                        match.matchName = dictionary["firstName"] as? String
                        self.matches.append(match)
                    }
                }
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    self.matchList.reloadData()
                    print(self.matches.count)
                }
            }
        }
    }

// function to convert image url into UIImage
private func icon(_ imageURL: String, imageView: UIImageView) {
        let url = URL(string: imageURL)
        var image: UIImage?
        var imageData:Data?
        if url == nil {
            print("Code failed here...")
            imageView.image =  #imageLiteral(resourceName: "ic_person_outline_white_2x")
        } else {
            URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url!) { (data, response, error) in
                if error != nil {
                    print("error")
                    DispatchQueue.main.async {
                        imageView.image = UIImage(imageLiteralResourceName: "ic_person_outline_white_2x")
                    }
                } else {
                    DispatchQueue.main.async {
                        imageData = data
                        image = UIImage(data: imageData!)
                        imageView.image = image!
                    }
                }
            }.resume()
        }
    }
// Data model
class MatchData: NSObject {
    var matchImage: String?
    var matchName: String?
}

// additional details
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "InboxCell", for: indexPath) as! InboxCell
        let matchInfo = matches[indexPath.row]
        cell.userLabel.text = matchInfo.matchName
        icon(matchInfo.matchImage ?? "", imageView: cell.userImage)
        //icon always returns nil value but Userlabel returns name value
        return cell
    }
```

The expected result is to have a cell that displays images along with the name of the user the image belongs too. The actual results is the name of the users profile and a nil value for the image.

Comment: IMO, you're going to have of issues with that code. You should be doing very little processing when working with the tableView; your dataSource should be populated before displaying the tableView i.e. load the names & images and store those in your datasource, then when populating each cell, it will quickly pull from that datasource instead of trying to download that image as you scroll. Also, you may want to consider using Cloud Storage to store the photos. Lastly, this `DispatchQueue.main.async` is not needed in Firebase closures to make UI calls - UI calls are always run on the main thread.

Comment: I think I may have found a solution to retrieve the image but, as you pointed out, I did notice slow processing time. I am not extremely experienced with collection views so could you show me an example of how to practically prefetch the data before the cell loads.

Comment: With the code in the question, you're loading all of the users (one at a time). How many users will you have in total? If it's an enormous amount of users, then you may want to leverage pagination so you don't overload the device.

Comment: lets say that I could end up with around 50 users in a given pool. I have reusable cells in place so only visible cells load.

Comment: You could vastly simplify that code but keeping the profileUrl in the same node as the other user data (like their name) and then read the user node, load the pic and refresh the tableView. You may want to consider using Firebase Storage for the image data as well.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you append match to your matchlist before your observeSingleEventOf callback completes. Match updates when the image is received, but has already been added.

```
if let dictionary = snapshot.value as? [String: AnyObject] {
    match.matchName = dictionary["firstName"] as? String
}
if matchUID != uid {
    Database.database().reference().child("profile_images").child(matichUID).observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (data) in
         if let imageDict = data.value as? [String: AnyObject] {
              match.matchImage = imageDict["imageOne"] as? String
         }
         self.matches.append(match)
         DispatchQueue.main.async {
              self.matchList.reloadData()
         }
    })

} else {
    self.matches.append(match)
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
         self.matchList.reloadData()
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm pulling the information from 2 different databases. The first database being users and the second database is profile_images(using the uid from users to find the corresponding image in profile_images).

Comment: I see that, let me update my redundant code. But you still need to wait for the image callback before appending to your global array of matches.

Comment: Thanks, its definitely making me scratch my head for sure.